# What can I replace tuple(sorted(my_string)) with in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, set

I want to use something like "characters where order does not matter" as the key to build a dictionary in Python.

Like "abc" and "cba" can give me the same hash index, and "aab" and "ab" give me different hash indices.

I found one way is to use `tuple(sorted(my_string))` to hashable a list of characters, but it may require O(NlogN) time complexity.

I tried to use `Counter`, but it is not hashable. `Frozenset` is hashable, but it does not allow duplicates.

Is there a better way (O(N) time complexity) to replace `tuple(sorted(my_string))`?

If there are mistakes above, please correct me. Thank you!

Comment: Just use `''.join(sorted(my_string))`.  The tuple is unnecessary.  There is nothing wrong with O(N log N) algorithms--many algorithms are O(N log N), and yet we still use them.

Comment: What is `triple`? Do you mean `tuple`?

Comment: @interjay Sorry it is a typo. Yes, I mean `tuple`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `O(N)` time complexity with `frozenset(Counter(my_string).items())`. You may want to time whether this actually wins in practice, though, because the constant factor of this code might be high enough to outweigh the extra logarithmic factor of `''.join(sorted(my_string))`.

Comment: Thank you! When I tried to test the time, I found `frozenset(Counter("bob")) == frozenset(Counter("boo"))` would give me `True`. I am not sure where went wrong.

Comment: @JayWong: You didn't call `items`.

Comment: Wow, I see! I am still curious why `frozenset(Counter("bob")) == frozenset(Counter("boo"))` would return `True`. `Counter("bob")` and `Counter("boo")` are two different objects.

Comment: @JayWong Iterating over a `Counter` gives the keys without the counts. Calling `items()` gives the keys and counts.